# Calculating returns with trading costs

Tags: trading, day-trading, transaction

This perhaps is an over simplification of calculating trading returns while including trading costs. I've made some assumptions - the commission for investing and extracting an investment is 1% and 2% respectively. The commissions do not change over the trading period which in this case is 5 time steps. I've used Python code to perform the calculations.

Set of positive and negative percentage changes in price for a given asset over 5 time steps is `{0.031% , 0.00121% , 0.0231% , -0.0213% , -0.0121%}`.

The commission to enter an investment is 1% of the invested amount, the commission to exit an investment is 2% of the current value of the invested amount.

**If I invest 1 euro in this asset, is the following correct?**

**1.**

The final investment amount if I do not trade the investment until $t=5$ is:
the final percentage change amount at $t=5$ which is `'initial invested amount' + '% change' - 'commission to enter' - 'commission to exit'`, therefore:

```
initial_investment_amt = 1

comission_in_amt = 1

comission_out_amt = 2

price_change = -.0121

return_amt = (initial_investment_amt + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100) = 0.97 which represents a loss of 1 - .97 = .03
```

**2.**

The final investment amount if I trade the investment at each time step until $t=5$ is:

```
initial_investment_amt = 1

comission_in_amt = 1

comission_out_amt = 2

price_change = .031

return_amt_1 = (initial_investment_amt + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = .00121

return_amt_2 = (return_amt_1 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = .0231

return_amt_3 = (return_amt_2 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = -.0213

return_amt_4 = (return_amt_3 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

price_change = -.0121

return_amt_5 = (return_amt_4 + (price_change / 100)) - (comission_in_amt / 100) - (comission_out_amt / 100)

print(return_amt_1)
print(return_amt_2)
print(return_amt_3)
print(return_amt_4)
print(return_amt_5)
```

prints :

```
0.97031
0.9403220999999999
0.9105530999999999
0.8803400999999998
0.8502190999999998
```

which represents a loss of $1 - 0.85 = 0.15$.